# Git configuration for local and remote web servers. Where to start?

Tags: git, web-services, github, web, ftp

I am part of a 10-members team and we build websites (dozens of them, ~9gb each). Since the company is old-fashioned we don't use git nor any kind version control, instead we have 3 different kind of servers (usually running windows server):

- **local server** (in a room near our office) for testing, once we're satisfied with the local testing we push the changes via ftp in a
- **preview server** (remote), used by the client to validate our new features. If the client is satified, we push the changes via ftp in the
- **official server** (remote), which is used by the consumer

As it can be seen we are, in fact, using 3-style branches: test, preview and master.

But we do not have a server for each of us:

We access the local server (folders) and directly modify the files,
and via the browser we see the changes. Usually we do not access the
same file at the same time so we do not have conflict.

I know we should run the server in our personal computer, make the changes we need and then push them in the remote preview and official servers...But we can't do this way, cause we already have 7 different workstation (in the room near our office) running all the local websites.

Maybe we sould:
do not change the way we work in local, set up git in all the server so:
we push the changes from *local server* to *preview* and *official server*.

So, how can I configure git to our needs? Are there some kind of
 strategies I should study?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to [a successful branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/): as you mention, you will then have 3 branches (test, preview, master) that you would manage from your test workstation (merging the changes to `preview` and `master`).

Then you will push to the different remote, i.e. you need to define one for each server you want to publish to. Each server will checkout the relevant branch as `git checkout -b preview origin/preview` for instance).

Now the trick is you cannot push to the working copy (the branch you have checked out, which is `preview` in the example above). You need to push to `origin/preview` instead. On the preview server, you then need to perform a `git rebase`. Additionally, you can create a post-update hook on the remote servers that performs `git rebase` upon incoming update.

As for working all together in the same fileset, well, this requires the an additional step to the usual coordination you used to have: the developers need to be careful to commit only their own changes. Besides, you cannot work on a separate branch as proposed in the workflow, since you branch the entire project. You are doomed to stick to the `test` branch.